# WKExtension Delegate to trigger WKInterfaceController Method

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

I'm trying to trigger a method within a WKInterfaceController from the WKExtension Delegate I'm not quite start on this.

Lets say:

```
- (void) sessionReachabilityDidChange:(WCSession *)session
{
    if (session.reachable) {
        // call interfacecontroller.h/.m method doStuff

    }
}
```

it has to be something silly I'm missing right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your delegate callback send a notification that the interface controller can subscribe to.

Another option would be to have the interface controller KVO the WCSession reachable property.

Comment: I went with this route, thank... wasn't really thinking clear when I asked this question lol